# Dim n variables where n is a user defined number

Tags: vb.net

I have to dim n variables in my software, where n is a number that user types in the interface. I'd start with a for loop, in order to declare these variables, with something like:

```
for i = 0 to n
    dim r.i as IRow = worksheet.CreateRow(i)
next
```

This is what I think but obviously I know that's wrong. Does anyone knows if this is possible? I can't create neither List(Of) nor arrays because these are rows of an excel file I'm trying to export, otherwise NPOI returns me error.

Comment: You should be able to use a List or array as long as they are declared correctly. `List(Of IRow)` doesn't work? What error do your get?

Comment: I can decorare them as list(of iRow) but how can I set the size of the row? I mean, how can I declare n rows with n different names?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What does Excel have anything to do with not using a List? You can absolutely use `worksheet.CreateRow()` with a list:

```
Dim rows As New List(Of IRow)
For i As Integer = 0 to n - 1
    rows.Add(worksheet.CreateRow(i))
Next
```

Now the name of each row is `row(0)`, `row(1)`, `row(2)` **...** `row(n - 1)`

If you've tried this and NPOI is giving you an error, you should show that code around where the error is thrown and tell us what the error is.

---

Based on comments:

```
'Assuming everything has the same number of entries as ListBox1, per the comments
Dim rows As New List(Of IRow)
Dim row As IRow = worksheet.CreateRow(0)
row.CreateCell(0).SetCellValue("Time")
row.CreateCell(1).SetCellValue("hrr")
For i As Integer = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1
    row = worksheet.CreateRow(i+1)
    row.CreateCell(0).SetCellValue(ListBox1.Items(i))
    row.CreateCell(1).SetCellValue(ListBox2.Items(i))
    rows.Add(row)
Next i
```

Comment: If you have to move the `rows` list declaration to somewhere that's still in scope later, then do that. Then you reference each row with names I provided: `rows(0)`, `rows(1)`, etc to find them again for the second column.  Even better, a `For Each row As IRow in rows`. Better still, you'll likely have much better performance finding all of the column data for each row up front, to only make one pass through your data.

Comment: Ok, I'm filling the first columns as follows:          `For i = 0 To t                r.Add(worksheet.CreateRow(CDbl(Form10.ListBox1.Items(i))))
Next` but I have two issues: the first regards how to fill the next column with the content of Form10.ListBox2.Items; the second one regards an Implicit conversion error (from double to integer).

Comment: What do you do if `ListBox1` and `ListBox2` have different numbers of items?

Comment: They won't. They are meant to be always of the same size. They are the lists of point rispectively of X-axis and Y-axis to build a graph

Comment: I can't understand how could I fill rows with those values. Previously I wrote   `r1.CreateCell(0).SetCellValue(ich.CreateRichTextString("Time"))
r2.CreateCell(0).SetCellValue(ich.CreateRichTextString("hrr"))
For i = 0 To t
r1.CreateCell(i + 1).SetCellValue(CDbl(Form10.ListBox1.Items(i)))
r2.CreateCell(i + 1).SetCellValue(CDbl(Form10.ListBox2.Items(i)))
next`

Comment: Ok It's working. How could I add an header on the first row now?

Comment: Create your header first. Start at 1 instead of 0 and go to Count instead of Count - 1

Comment: Perfect and so I did.